# Is there a built in way to clean POST

Tags: php, post, filter, data-cleaning

Say I want to trim ALL values that come into my system via the POST (`$_POST`)
Or, even apply more complex filters.
Is there an intrinsic way to do it (Post can also be an array of arrays...)
I do have a bootstrap file where I currently do it using `array_walk_recursive` or something similar.

```
function trim_array(&$elm){
    if(is_string($elm)){
        $elm=trim($elm);    
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($_POST,'trim_array');
```

Comment: No intrinsic way... `array_walk_recursive()` is probably the most obvious and best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function recursive_trim($arr) {
        foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
            if(is_string($v)) {
                $arr[$k] = trim($v);
            } else if(is_array($v)) {
                recursive_trim($arr[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    recursive_trim($_POST);
```

Comment: or `array_walk_recursive($_POST, "trim");`

Comment: he can add his "more complex filters" easily here

Comment: @marin, you will need create a function that uses trim, u can't use trim directly

Comment: @Itay that's not true, trim is a function.

Comment: yes, but it does not work on references, it returns the cleaned value.

Answer (score 0):

For triming a value, I'd definitely use the method you wanted - `array_walk_recursive`, but be sure not to trim values which should stay the same, such as passwords.

For more complex filters, I'd say, that it depends. Sometimes you could just use `array_walk_recursive` but there are cases when you just can't.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned `array_walk_recursive` is good one to use. Another one would be `call_user_func` which I prefer to use.